# How to find measures in a dataSet

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, data-science, datamart

So, I have this dataset here: https://www.kaggle.com/johnolafenwa/us-census-data#adult-training.csv

I am new to datawarehouses. I understand what a measure is but I'm not sure what justifies itself as a measure for a fact table? In this dataset what columns can be measures?

The way I have seen is measures are like `Count()` or `Avg()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Measures** are numerical values that mathematical functions work on. For example, a sales revenue column is a measure because you can find out a total or average the data (but not only total or average it depends on your need).

When dimensions and measures work together, they help answer complex business questions.

A **metric** is a quantifiable measure that is used to track and assess the status of a specific process. That said, here is the difference: a measure is a fundamental or unit-specific term—a metric can literally be derived from one or more measures.

A **fact table** is used in the dimensional model in data warehouse design. A fact table is  found at the center of a star schema or snowflake schema surrounded by dimension tables.

A **fact table** consists of facts of a particular business process e.g., sales revenue by month by product. Facts are also known as measurements or metrics. A fact table record captures a measurement or a metric.